# Performance questions uploading Block Blob to Azure

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, azure, azure-blob-storage

I developed a C# DotNet application that backs up a SQL Server database to an Azure Block Blob.

However it is extremely slow when compared to `SQL BACKUP TO URL`.  When running a performance counter on network activity I see that `BACKUP TO URL` is sending at about 30 MBPS while my application is sending at around 5 MBPS when it sends a block to the Blob.  Is there some setting in Azure that controls the transmission speed of a block sent with `PutBlock`?  I do know that SQL backup creates a Page Blob, while I am using a Block Blob.  Should that make any difference?

Comment: Can you share your code? and what's the size of the data?

Comment: It is not a huge project, but probably bigger than can be put in-line here.  What do you recommend?  I could upload the code to my server  and provide a link to it here.

Answer (score 1):

For block blobs, in SDK, there is a `ParallelOperationThreadCount` property(Gets or sets the number of blocks that may be simultaneously uploaded.) of the `BlobRequestOptions` object(see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/understanding-block-blobs--append-blobs--and-page-blobs#about-block-blobs) for details). By using this property, it can be faster to upload blobs.

A sample of using this property:

```
var requestOption = new BlobRequestOptions()
{
    ParallelOperationThreadCount = 5 //Gets or sets the number of blocks that may be simultaneously uploaded.
};
```